# How can I make pylint throw an error if a particular method is used?

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

There is a method `thirdPartyObject.problem_method` that I want to prevent from being used in a repository. I like the other functionality of the library this method comes from, so I just want to restrict this method from being used (or at least require some sort of `#ignore error` comment when it is used, so people are cognizant of it). I'd like to use static analysis to catch this - is there a way to do this in pylint?

Answer (score -2):

You could try to check if it's used with an if statement, maybe something like this:

```
Import sys #to stop the script
If (i don't know how you could check if it's used):
    Print('you can't use that')
Sys.exit(0)
```